# IC Identification - TT617-18-1

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Does anyone have any ideas what this chip is please?  Tried searching but to no avail.

[image]

(I think the chip Identifier is the TT617-18-1).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a "Call Progress Tone Generator"

please follow the link
https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2001/pr57/M-991.PDF

Comment: Do you have a link to a datasheet or manufacturer's web site or something?

Comment: I edited the answer pls check

Comment: Looks right. Also the crystal you can see on the picture is close to pin 6 and 7, which is the crystal inputs.

Comment: Yeh the crystal you have to connect to pin 6 and 7